# setting up a button without using storyboards in xcode swift

Tags: swift3, viewcontroller

I am experimenting not using storyboards and just writing the UI in code. I have the button attributes, i added to the subview to the viewDidLoad and also set up the constraints. I should be seeing a button in the middle of the screen.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var setupButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 80, g: 101, b: 161, a: 256)
        button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        view.addSubview(setupButton)
        coolButton()

    }

    func coolButton() {

        setupButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        setupButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        setupButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -24)
        setupButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)




    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}

extension UIColor {

    convenience init(r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat, a: CGFloat) {
        self.init(red: r/255, green: g/255, blue: b/255, alpha: a/255)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

From NSLayoutConstraint docs:

> Note that only active constraints affect the calculated layout.
>
> For newly created constraints, the active property is NO by default.

You just have to set the `isActive` property to `true` for your constraints.

```
setupButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
setupButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
setupButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
setupButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
```